# Multidimensional array in poker program

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, poker

I'm not sure how to make the multidimensional array able to perform the same task as the other three I am supposed to get rid of. Would I just simply replace all the places with the other arrays with just the one Multi? This is especially hard for me since I do not play cards and the logic behind the card game makes no sense to me.

***DIRECTIONS***

I need to remove the num_in_rank, num_in_suit, and card_exists arrays. Have the program store the cards in a 5 x 2 array instead. Each row of the array will represent a card. For example, if the array is named hand, then hand(0)(0) will store the rank of the first card and hand(0)(1) will store the suit of the first card.

```
/* Classifies a poker hand */

#include <stdbool.h>   /* C99 only */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_RANKS 13
#define NUM_SUITS 4
#define NUM_CARDS 5

/* external variables */
int num_in_rank[NUM_RANKS];
int num_in_suit[NUM_SUITS];
bool straight, flush, four, three;
int pairs;   /* can be 0, 1, or 2 */
/* prototypes */
void read_cards(void);
void analyze_hand(void);
void print_result(void);

/**********************************************************
* main: Calls read_cards, analyze_hand, and print_result *
*       repeatedly.                                      *
**********************************************************/
int main(void)
{
for (;;) {
    read_cards();
    analyze_hand();
    print_result();
}
}
/**********************************************************
* read_cards: Reads the cards into the external          *
*             variables num_in_rank and num_in_suit;     *
*             checks for bad cards and duplicate cards.  *
**********************************************************/
void read_cards(void)
{
bool card_exists[NUM_RANKS][NUM_SUITS];
char ch, rank_ch, suit_ch;
int rank, suit;
bool bad_card;
int cards_read = 0;

for (rank = 0; rank < NUM_RANKS; rank++) {
    num_in_rank[rank] = 0;
    for (suit = 0; suit < NUM_SUITS; suit++)
        card_exists[rank][suit] = false;
}

for (suit = 0; suit < NUM_SUITS; suit++)
    num_in_suit[suit] = 0;
while (cards_read < NUM_CARDS) {
    bad_card = false;

    printf("Enter a card: ");

    rank_ch = getchar();
    switch (rank_ch) {
    case '0':           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    case '2':           rank = 0; break;
    case '3':           rank = 1; break;
    case '4':           rank = 2; break;
    case '5':           rank = 3; break;
    case '6':           rank = 4; break;
    case '7':           rank = 5; break;
    case '8':           rank = 6; break;
    case '9':           rank = 7; break;
    case 't': case 'T': rank = 8; break;
    case 'j': case 'J': rank = 9; break;
    case 'q': case 'Q': rank = 10; break;
    case 'k': case 'K': rank = 11; break;
    case 'a': case 'A': rank = 12; break;
    default:            bad_card = true;
    }
    suit_ch = getchar();
    switch (suit_ch) {
    case 'c': case 'C': suit = 0; break;
    case 'd': case 'D': suit = 1; break;
    case 'h': case 'H': suit = 2; break;
    case 's': case 'S': suit = 3; break;
    default:            bad_card = true;
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    if (ch != ' ') bad_card = true;

    if (bad_card)
        printf("Bad card; ignored.\n");
    else if (card_exists[rank][suit])
        printf("Duplicate card; ignored.\n");
    else {
        num_in_rank[rank]++;
        num_in_suit[suit]++;
        card_exists[rank][suit] = true;
        cards_read++;
    }
}
}
/**********************************************************
* analyze_hand: Determines whether the hand contains a   *
*               straight, a flush, four-of-a-kind,       *
*               and/or three-of-a-kind; determines the   *
*               number of pairs; stores the results into *
*               the external variables straight, flush,  *
*               four, three, and pairs.                  *
**********************************************************/
void analyze_hand(void)
{
int num_consec = 0;
int rank, suit;
straight = false;
flush = false;
four = false;
three = false;
pairs = 0;
/* check for flush */
for (suit = 0; suit < NUM_SUITS; suit++)
if (num_in_suit[suit] == NUM_CARDS)
    flush = true;

/* check for straight */
rank = 0;
while (num_in_rank[rank] == 0) rank++;
for (; rank < NUM_RANKS && num_in_rank[rank] > 0; rank++)
    num_consec++;
if (num_consec == NUM_CARDS) {
    straight = true;
    return;
}

/* check for 4-of-a-kind, 3-of-a-kind, and pairs */
for (rank = 0; rank < NUM_RANKS; rank++) {
    if (num_in_rank[rank] == 4) four = true;
    if (num_in_rank[rank] == 3) three = true;
    if (num_in_rank[rank] == 2) pairs++;
}
}
/**********************************************************
* print_result: Prints the classification of the hand,   *
*               based on the values of the external      *
*               variables straight, flush, four, three,  *
*               and pairs.                               *
**********************************************************/
void print_result(void)
{
if (straight && flush) printf("Straight flush");
else if (four)         printf("Four of a kind");
else if (three &&
    pairs == 1)   printf("Full house");
else if (flush)        printf("Flush");
else if (straight)     printf("Straight");
else if (three)        printf("Three of a kind");
else if (pairs == 2)   printf("Two pairs");
else if (pairs == 1)   printf("Pair");
else                   printf("High card");

printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: I guess the short answer is yes. You need to get rid of redundant arrays and use a single two dimensional array as you described above. I suppose this is 5 card poker hence the 5 x 2 array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to help you visualize it first define the multidimensional array, then use constants to access the indexes

ie.

```
//you could also use namespaces and enums or static class variables, const is simpler
const int RANK = 0; //or CARD_RANK if ambiguous/conflicting
const int SUIT = 1; //or CARD_SUIT if ambiguous
int cards[5][2]; //first index is card, second index is data about the card

//access first card's suit
int temp = cards[0][SUIT];
```

Assuming the program runs already, and all you need to do is this, then just do it and everything will work. The game seems to be poker or a variation btw.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try to apply your advice and report back asap.